# Is there a way to make APIs temporarily unavailable on Azure?

Tags: api, azure, azure-functions, http-status-code-503

I'd like to implement a 503 feature for my APIs whenever system is in maintenance so that users get the appropriate HTTP response message. As of now, the way I'm doing this is to store a flag in the database and check it with every API request to see if I should be issuing a 503 error. However, I'm thinking there could be a different way to do this on Azure. Is there any setting I could turn on and off on the portal for this purpose so that I don't need to add another lookup trip to the database? I'm using `Azure Functions` for my services.

Comment: If you put APIM (API Management - an Azure service) in front of your API you get total control of this. Whether it's worth it in your situation I'm not sure (there's a cost) but worth at least looking at.

Comment: You can simply introduce an AppSetting that you check in your function. And then return a 503. Additionally you can add a timestamp when your api is back and return that in the http header with your 503.

Comment: @SebastianAchatz Great idea! Thanks.

Comment: @SebastianAchatz You could post your comment as an answer for others to refer.

Comment: @JoyWang You're right. Added my comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply introduce an AppSetting that you check in your function. And then return a HTTP 503. Additionally you can add a timestamp when your API is back and return that in the HTTP header (Retry-After) with your 503.